# Same condition logic generating two very different byte codes for AtomicBooleans in Java. Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, cas, locks

If I do this, my program works very fine:

```
if (atomicBoolean1.get() == false && atomicBoolean2.get() == true 
     && !atomicBoolean1.compareAndSet(false, true)) {

    continue;
}
```

Now if I do this, everything breaks:

```
if (atomicBoolean1.get() == false && atomicBoolean2.get() == true) {

    continue;
}

if (!atomicBoolean1.compareAndSet(false, true)) {

    continue;
}
```

Am I getting insane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`continue` jumps to the next iteration.

They both are not same. Same should be

```
if (atomicBoolean1.get() == false && atomicBoolean2.get() == true) {   
  if (!atomicBoolean1.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
      continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow !!!!! Why? I have two branches instead of one? Logically it is the same, so now I am confused.

Comment: Now your two conditions workings independently. You have to relate them with one other. :)

Comment: @JohnPristine, when you do a "continue" it doesn't go to "next line". Maybe you misunderstood the "continue" statement.

Comment: @anonymous Oh no. What a silly mistake. I am getting old. They are not logically the same. I am sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not doing exactly similar things in above 2 cases.

In case1,

```
atomicBoolean1.get() == false && atomicBoolean2.get() == true
```

if above 2 conditions satisfied only,

```
atomicBoolean1.compareAndSet(false, true)
```

function is calling.

But in case2,

```
atomicBoolean1.get() == false && atomicBoolean2.get() == true
```

if above 2 conditions satisfied, it will go back to loop start.
so will not call

```
atomicBoolean1.compareAndSet(false, true)
```

If those 2 conditions failed only, it will call

```
atomicBoolean1.compareAndSet(false, true)
```

I think, I may cause any problem.

Lets give more details about your program and what you are trying to do.
It may help to figure out the issue.